# Multiple keyword search in MongdoDB using Morphia, For a document with multiple text indexed field

Tags: mongodb, full-text-search, morphia, database

I am in need of your suggestion to search multiple keywords in a document where there is multiple fields indexed.

Lets say i have a entity Employee as below, and i have multiple fields indexed in this document.

```
@Entity("employee")
@Indexes({@Index(fields = @Field(value = "employeeName", type = IndexType.TEXT)),
          @Index(fields = @Field(value = "employeeDept", type = IndexType.TEXT)),})
public class Employee {

    @Id private ObjectId id;

    private long empId;

    private String employeeName;

    private String employeeDept;

    ..... Many other fields!!!!
```

So i want to do a multiple keyword search ( $in ) in this document.. and get the result list. I am using Morphia framework and need your suggestion using the same

Now i am using the latest Morphia(1.+) and MongoDB(3.+). In morphia i can do a multiple keyword search( $in ) only on a particular field  and not on a entire document.

```
datastore.find(Employee.class).field("employeeName").in(Arrays.asList("name1","name2")).limit(BATCH_SIZE).asList();
```

but lets say i have a search query to find `employeeName deptName` .. if anyone of the keyword matches i want to return the document  in my search results.

How can i do this ?

Update

---

I am not using search() on the entire document because , i am considering each word as a individual seach criteria.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
Query<Employee> query = datastore.createQuery(Employee.class);
List<String> names = Arrays.asList("name1","name2");

query.or(
     query.criteria("employeeName").hasAnyOf(names),
     query.criteria("employeeDept").hasAnyOf(names)
);
List<Employee> employees = query.limit(BATCH_SIZE).asList();
```

`IndexType.TEXT` is not helping you with that query — if you're not using `search()` you're not using full-text search. But I think an index on each attribute (and not a combination) is the right approach, since `or` queries are executed independently and merged.

PS: I wouldn't expect this to be too fast with bigger datasets.

Comment: Hi @Xeraa,

I got the similar issue but a different one : I got Users class with 4 properties : initials, firstName, middleName, lastName
On the given user's search text how can I combine the criteria and search properly. For e.g. if user search <firstname lastname> it needs to find contains exact string in all those criteria combined! not individual string as this can return false resultsets.  Is there any work around in Morphia for such case?

Comment: Do you know which field is which? Then you can just do: `.field("firstname").equal("...").field("lastname").equal("...")`